# amazon affiliate code for rewards website

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have the iframe code for amazon banner. What I am trying to do is post this banner on our rewards website, and for each order placed through this link, a certain no of points will be added to that persons account in our website. A similar thing like linkshare and commission junction. can i also do the same for amazon? Is this even possible through amazon?
If so please guide me here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check the Amazon Affiliates' terms of service to see if you can incentivize clicks like that.